# knockout choose viewmodel depend on attribute

Tags: knockout.js

I have something like that:

**Html:**

```
<div data-bind="??? with?" id="MainItem">
  <input type="text" id="MainQuantity" value="12" data-bind="text: Quantity"> шт
  <input type="button" value="Buy" data-bind="click: CartAdd" data-good-id="2134" />
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
var MainViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  var items = [ { Id:2134, Quantity: 12 }, .. ]; // this data from json

  self.CartAdd = function (data, event) {
    var id = $(event.target).attr("data-good-id");
    $.grep(self.items, function (i) { return i.id == id }).
      each(function (i) { i.Quantity++; })
  }
}
```

So, I need to set the ViewModel for my #MainItem element, ViewModel should be from items array, selected by id, that placed in "data-good-id" attribute.

My end result should be, that Quantity property is binded to #MainQuantity element

Thank you.

Comment: What is the initial value of data-good-id attribute? How can it changed? Do you have any loop?

Comment: @SławomirRosiek, i don't have any loops here, html is generated by server, i can change html: add/del any attributes, but it's undesirable to change html-structure

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't want to use the *with* binding. Instead you can to do a foreach loop on your items and then access the access the **CartAdd** function on the parent context. Example:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <input type="text" id="MainQuantity" value="12" data-bind="text: Quantity">
    <input type="button" value="Buy" data-bind="click: $parent.CartAdd" data-good-id="2134" />
</div>
```

Excuse any typo but I am on the phone. Hope it helps.